# Why I'm retrieving null values and new line characters from SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dbnull

I imported a dataset from a CSV file into a SQLite database 3.1.1. I'm managing that database through SQLiteStudio. I'm suppose to retrieve 7,332 values at runtime in my C# code; not the 7,340 values I'm retrieving.

**Problem:**

I'm checking every row to see if the value being return is null. **However, there are no null values in the dataset or any empty rows.** I'm retrieving more rows than expected 7,340 rows versus 7,332 from the dataset. I'm also retrieving a row that in the column 'NAME' contains this value: **"\n".**.

The code works fine; however where does this "\n" value comes from? Why it is messing up my data with null values and with "\n" values?

**Solution Expected**

The original code didn't have to check for nulls with the old dataset, as again; the data does not contain null values. Now that I imported a new dataset I'm having this problem. How can I get rid of the null values when retrieving and reading the data through the ExecuteReader()?

**Code:**

```
   using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME, STATE_FIPS, COUNTY_FIPS, BEDS, ICU_BEDS FROM Hospitals";
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string name = Convert.ToString(reader.GetString(0));
                        int? stateFIPS = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(1)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1)));
                        int? countyFIPS = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(2)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2)));
                        int? numBeds = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(3)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3)));
                        int? numICUBeds = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(4)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(4)));

                        hospitals.Add(new Hospital()
                        {
                            Name = reader.GetString(0),
                            StateFIPS = Convert.ToInt32(stateFIPS),
                            CountyFIPS = Convert.ToInt32(countyFIPS),
                            NumBeds = Convert.ToInt32(numBeds),
                            NumICUBeds = Convert.ToInt32(numICUBeds),

                        });

                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
```

**How I'm managing the import from SQLite**

[image]

Comment: `int? stateFIPS = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(1)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1)));` will never return null value, because you return 0 as a default value. Please check if your additional rows have all int values set to 0;

Comment: 2nd thing: `StateFIPS = Convert.ToInt32(stateFIPS)` there is no need to convert int (which is Int32) to Int32

Comment: If you read correctly; it says that I had to do that in order to make it work...My main question is why I'm retrieving "\n" if there is no value like that in the database.

Comment: Have you checked with SQLiteStudio that your DB contains 7,332 rows? And I am not asking how many rows you have in your csv file, but rather how many entries your DB contains. I am assuming that there might be error with importing / structure of your csv file.

Comment: Yes. It matches...what I'm thinking is that special characters might be at fault here? And if so; how do I fix having commas in my name value and other special characters?

Comment: Is Name the first field in each line in the CSV?  Does each line in your csv end with both a carriage return (\r) and a linefeed (\n)?  Perhaps the import is only considering the carriage return as the line delimiter and including the linefeed as part of the first field in the next line?